# Are DA4R work items with output files de facto limited to 60 minutes by S3?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have a Design Automation activity for Revit that runs a process on a model and all its links, resulting in an output.zip file. Crawling the link reference tree can involve opening many models in sequence and take a significant amount of time.

I was previously using the following endpoint to save my output.zip file:

```
PUT buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectKey}
```

However, since [that endpoint is deprecated](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-PUT/), I recently migrated my code and Design Automation activities to use the recommended [S3 signed upload](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) instead:

```
GET buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectKey}/signeds3upload
```

The problem with this is that I am required to generate the URL before submitting my Design Automation work item and the URL expires after a maximum of 60 minutes. This introduces a constraint where the link expires and my work item fails with status `failedUpload` if it takes longer than 60 minutes, despite the [Design Automation process time limit](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/) for Revit being 12 hours.

The signed upload URLs effectively limit the maximum process time to an hour, but my work items sometimes take longer this. What can I do to get around this constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide OSS URN like `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:<bucket_name>/<object_key>` for the Input or Output, with a valid Authorization token. Design Automation will extend the token if it is expired when uploading happens.

Refer to https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/ and https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/